# How to fetch data from checkboxes in Laravel using multiple queries

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel

I want to fetch data from more tables by running multiple queries. 
For example I want to fetch the education detail of a student just by click check box education.
Similarly personal detail, publications detail by clicking check boxes for personal, publication.

How can I do this?
My code is given here
Controller code is ExampleController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Auth;


class ExampleController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
         $result = DB::table('education')->get();
         $data = DB::table('publications')->get();

         return view('triel',compact('result','data'));
    }

}
```

and my view file is trail.blade.php and its code is given here. I have not defined the check boxes because I dont know how to retrieve data in check boxes.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container"><br>
    <h1>Irfan Khan Triel Page</h1>

    <div class="text text-success text-center">
        PHD Research
    </div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                PHD Research Area
            </th>
            <th>University</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>

     @foreach($result as $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$value->research_area}}</td>

            <td>{{$value->univ}}</td>

            <td>{{$value->country}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
       </table>

        <div class="text text-success text-center">
       Publications Detail
    </div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Title
            </th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Year</th>
        </tr>

     @foreach($data as $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$value->title}}</td>

            <td>{{$value->status}}</td>

            <td>{{$value->year}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach

    </table>

    @endsection
```

and the routes is given here.

```
Route::get('triel','ExampleController@index');
```

Here I want to show my data in view while checking publications detail or education details or both, but I dont know how to do this. Please help me any body. thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do. Can you share what you tried so far?

Comment: It's not super clear, but if I got it right you should set some endpoints to retrieve data with ajax once the checkbox is clicked and populate with data. Another option would be to fetch everything before rendering and using css set display to none and toggle it when the checkbox is checked.